# ajax form opening but not updating

Tags: php, jquery

I am loading a form on to a page and into a div as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#comments').load('/pages/includes/comments.php', { user:"<?=$user?>", id:"<?=$id?>"
});
</script>
```

The page loads fine and any comments in the system show but when i try  to add new comments its simply not working, comments.php below (if i 'include' the file as opposed to ajax it works fine btw):

```
require '/home/php_/lib/dbconnect.inc';

$comments_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments_id']);
$comments = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

/*******************************************************/
/****************** add item
/*******************************************************/

if ($_POST[additem] == '1'){ // AA

    $additem = mysql_query("
    insert into comments (
    id,
    user_id,
    comments
     )
    VALUES (
    '$id',
    '$user',
    '$comments'
    )",$db);

    if(!$additem) { echo "input error ".mysql_error(); exit; } // debug

} // close AA

/*******************************************************/
/****************** end add item
/*******************************************************/


$coms = mysql_query("select * from comments where id = '$id';",$db);
if(!$coms) { echo "coms error ".mysql_error(); exit; } // debug

if (mysql_num_rows($coms)>0){ // 55

    while($databack44 = mysql_fetch_array($coms)){ // 55

    echo '<div style="width:100%; float:left;">'.$databack44[comments].'</div>';

        } 

        } // 55

        else {  

        echo 'No Comments';

        }

?>      

<form method="post" action="#">
    <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="button green">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="additem" value="1">
    </form>
```

Comment: what error do you get on ajax debug it using fire bug

Comment: @MianKhurramIjaz - no errors at all

Answer (score 2):

That is because once you submitted the new comment it will acting as a form submit and it is not working as like AJAX.

Easiest way is to use a separate php file to save comments and [**jquery form**](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin
add this to `<HEAD>` tag in  **comment.php**

```
<HEAD>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                location.reload(); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</HEAD>
<?php 
$coms = mysql_query("select * from comments where id = '$id';",$db);
if(!$coms) { echo "coms error ".mysql_error(); exit; } // debug

if (mysql_num_rows($coms)>0){ // 55

    while($databack44 = mysql_fetch_array($coms)){ // 55

    echo '<div style="width:100%; float:left;">'.$databack44[comments].'</div>';

        } 

        } // 55

        else {  

        echo 'No Comments';

        }


?>
<form method="post" action="function.php" id="myForm">
    <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="button green">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="additem" value="1">
    </form>
```

**function.php**

```
if ($_POST[additem] == '1'){ // AA

    $additem = mysql_query("
    insert into comments (
    id,
    user_id,
    comments
     )
    VALUES (
    '$id',
    '$user',
    '$comments'
    )",$db);

    if(!$additem) { echo "input error ".mysql_error(); exit; } // debug

} // close AA
```

**jquery form plugin** is disabling the standard form submit function and send form data as ajax variables to the given **form action url**.

after sending data to the **function.php**, **comment.php** will be reloading by location.reload().

Now you have the new comments
Hope this helps

Comment: if you don't need to reload the page after adding the comment. let us know i will let you know another way of doing like facebook

Comment: many thanks vinu - yeah, the whole point of doing it this way is that i don't want to reload the page - thanks foe your help

Comment: Glad to help you friend. i have added another way of doing this without reloading page check that also. if this solve your problem,please accept it as answer okay

Answer (score 0):

Hey Darren glad to help you...

okay this is an another way to do this.
we need 3 pages.

1. comment.php
2. function.php
3. comment.js

**comment.php**

```
    <HEAD>
    <script>
            var id="<?php echo $_GET['id']?>"; 
            // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
            $(document).ready(function() { 
            //loading comments on page loading
              view_comment(id);
                }); 
            }); 
        </script> 
    </HEAD>

<div id="display_div"></div>
<form name="f1">
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="additem" value="1">
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="button green" onClick="javascript:add_comment(f1.id.value,f1.additem.value,f1.comments.value)">    
    </form>
```

**function.php**

```
<?php
    //view comments
    if($_GET['action']=="view_comment"){
    $coms = mysql_query("select * from comments where id = '$id';",$db);
    if(!$coms) { echo "coms error ".mysql_error(); exit; } // debug

    if (mysql_num_rows($coms)>0){ // 55

        while($databack44 = mysql_fetch_array($coms)){ // 55

        echo '<div style="width:100%; float:left;">'.$databack44[comments].'</div>';

            } 

            } // 55

            else {  

            echo 'No Comments';

            }


    }

    //add comments
    if($_POST['additem']=="1"){
$id=$_POST['id'];
$comments=$_POST['comment'];
     $additem = mysql_query("
        insert into comments (
        id,
        user_id,
        comments
         )
        VALUES (
        '$id',
        '$user',
        '$comments'
        )",$db);

        if(!$additem) { echo "input error ".mysql_error(); exit; }

    }
?>
```

**comment.js**

```
function view_comment(id){
$("#display_div").empty().html('<img src="pathtoaloadingimage" />');
   $("#display_div").load("pathtoyourfile/function.php?action=view_comment&id="+id).fadeOut('slow').hide().fadeIn('slow');

}

function add_comment(id,additem,comment){
    if(comment!=""){
 $("#display_div").empty().html('<img src="pathtoaloadingimage" />');
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://pathtoyourfile/function.php",
  data: "id="+id+"&additem="+additem+"&comment="+comment});
  $("#comments").val('');
  view_comment(id); 
    }else{
         alert('Comment is empty..! Please write something to comment.');
        return false; 
        }


}
```

Here we go now you have a AJAX comment page

NOTE:-add a loading image to your site and use that path to `pathtoaloadingimage` then it will make your site look nicer.so once you have submitted a new comment,loading image will display and after display your new comments at the same point. NO reloads anymore

Hope this helps you